# how to check if objedc has attribute false o true

Tags: python, object

I'm trying to check if any of the students are on probation and if they are, display which student please assist with the error code, the code is meant to check if anyone has violated probation, it also displays an error code, the except is normally key error, but when I was trying to figure out the problem i changed it to keyboard interrupt

if students[Student].is_on_probation:
KeyError: 0

```
  students = {}

try:
    while True:

        from Student import Student


        students['1'] = Student("Jim", "Business", 3.1, False)



        viewing = False

        viewingchange = input("Would you like to view something: ").lower()
        if viewingchange == "y":
            viewing = True
        elif viewingchange == "yes":
            viewing = True
        else:
            viewing = False
            add = input("Would you like to add someone: ")
            if add.lower() == "yes" or "y":
                adder = str(input("Who would you like to add: "))
                major = str(input("What is their major: "))
                gpa = float(input("GPA: "))
                is_on_probation = bool(input("is on probation: "))

                students[str(len(students)+1)] = Student(adder, major, gpa, is_on_probation)




        def checking():
            if viewing:
                checker = input("Would you like to view all students or student a/s: ")

                if checker.lower() == "a":
                    print(students)
                    checkfor = input("Check for: ")
                    if checkfor.lower() == "probation":
                        for Student in range(len(students)):
                            print("works")
                            if students[Student].is_on_probation:
                                print("yeppp")
                            else:
                                pass
                    checkerdouble = False
                elif checker.lower() == "s":
                    searchquery2 = input("And which attribute would you like to search: ")
                    test = input("Student ID: ")
                    dude = students[test]
                    if searchquery2.lower() == "Name".lower():
                        print(dude.name)
                    elif searchquery2.lower() == "Major".lower():
                        print(dude.major)
                    elif searchquery2.lower() == "GPA".lower():
                        print(dude.gpa)
                    elif searchquery2.lower() == "is on probation" or "iop" or "probation".lower():
                        print(dude.is_on_probation)
                    checkerdouble = True

        checking()




except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Error code: " + "45345593M3940249525")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your students dictionary uses string representations of numbers that start at str(1). So the loop should do the same. I think it would be better to just use int keys.

```
for student_id in map(str, range(1, len(students)):
    if students[student_id].is_on_probation:
        print(student_id)
```

This would work but it relies on the dictionary keys being dense. I would prefer to do:

```
for student_id in sorted(students, key=int):
    if students[student_id].is_on_probation:
        print(student_id)
```

Some might object to the indexing, as one can do:

```
for student_id, student in sorted(students.items(), key=lambda v: int(v[0])):
    if student.is_on_probation:
        print(student_id)
```